# Substring time component from a matrix

Tags: r, string, date, matrix

My data is in a 2 column matrix:

```
[3821,] "Meg Bear"                    "2009-06-29T21:34:03+0000"
[3822,] "Meentiee Khurana"            "2010-07-10T17:11:37+0000"
[3823,] "Meg Bear"                    "2009-06-29T21:34:03+0000"
[3824,] "Meentiee Khurana"            "2010-07-10T17:11:37+0000"
[3825,] "Anjul Sahu"                  "2009-06-26T18:14:44+0000"
```

I am trying to remove the time component from the 2nd column so I can perform grouping on date.

```
[3821,] "Meg Bear"                    "2009-06-29T21:34:03+0000"
```

should be

```
[3821,] "Meg Bear"                    "2009-06-29"
```

in a same or new matrix variable.

I tried few options but I cant get around this. I think I can loop over the data set but I am sure R has better option to perform matrix operation.

Comment: Try using `substr()`

Answer (score 2):

```
 str1 <- "2009-06-29T21:34:03+0000"
 gsub("T.*", "", str1)
 #[1] "2009-06-29"


  m1 <- cbind(c("Meg Bear", "Meentiee Khurana"), c("2009-06-29T21:34:03+0000", "2010-07-10T17:11:37+0000"))
  m1[,2] <- gsub("T.*", "", m1[,2])
 m1
 #      [,1]               [,2]        
 #[1,] "Meg Bear"         "2009-06-29"
 #[2,] "Meentiee Khurana" "2010-07-10"
```

Another option is to use `stringi` which would be faster

```
 library(stringi)
 unlist(stri_extract_all_regex(m1[,2], "^.*(?=[A-Z])"))
 #[1] "2009-06-29" "2010-07-10"
```

Comment: the count of rows are not certain so I need something that operates without providing specific value like `m1 <- cbind(c("Meg Bear", "Me...`

Comment: @Tejas Damania You showed an example with all the rows that have "T".  If it is not the case, you should have provided in the exmaple or mentioned in the text.  Please show an example that mimics your original dataset.

Comment: T is in all the rows but total rows may vary. I think my substr approach will be more elegant if I can look for T instead of 10th position.

Comment: @Tejas Damania  How does total rows affect the result?.  Have you even tried the method I showed?

Comment: I was just trying to show that it could be done, in case OP might need them. It looks like the times may be important in the data, because the same first-column values are occurring on the same day.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be simpler actually.

```
who1[,2] <- substr(who1[,2],1,10)
```

Comment: If you have a `data.frame` (not a `matrix`) the correct way would be `who1[,2] <- as.Date(who1[,2])` which will return a `Date` class and allow you subtract/add days like you do with a `numeric` value

Comment: this works but it changes the format to `[3825,] "Anjul Sahu"                  "1245945600"` in string format. My subsequent code fails when `> as.Date(who1[,2])
Error in charToDate(x)`

Comment: @Tejas Damania Please show what you want in the example rather than keeping others guessing

Comment: As I said, in case you have a `data.frame`, not a `matrix`. Buy you obviously have a matrix

Comment: Note that this would only work if you know for certain that "T" is the 11th character.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `as.Date`.  Since it probably won't cooperate when we assign it to the second column, we need to wrap it with `format` (or `as.character`).

```
> m[,2] <- format(as.Date(m[,2]))
> m
#     [,1]               [,2]        
#[1,] "Meg Bear"         "2009-06-29"
#[2,] "Meentiee Khurana" "2010-07-10"
#[3,] "Meg Bear"         "2009-06-29"
#[4,] "Meentiee Khurana" "2010-07-10"
#[5,] "Anjul Sahu"       "2009-06-26"
```

Another option would be `stringr`

```
> stringr::str_replace(m[,2], "T(.*)", "")
# [1] "2009-06-29" "2010-07-10" "2009-06-29" "2010-07-10" "2009-06-26"
```

You can also use `regexpr` with `substr`

```
> substr(m[,2], 1, regexpr("T", m[,2])-1)
# [1] "2009-06-29" "2010-07-10" "2009-06-29" "2010-07-10" "2009-06-26"
```

where `m` is

```
m <- 
structure(c("Meg Bear", "Meentiee Khurana", "Meg Bear", "Meentiee Khurana", 
"Anjul Sahu", "2009-06-29T21:34:03+0000", "2010-07-10T17:11:37+0000", 
"2009-06-29T21:34:03+0000", "2010-07-10T17:11:37+0000", "2009-06-26T18:14:44+0000"
), .Dim = c(5L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2")))
```

Comment: Why can't just `as.Date(m[,2])`

Comment: check `m[,2] <- as.Date(m[,2]); m`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ddf = structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Anjul Sahu", 
"Meentiee Khurana", "Meg Bear"), class = "factor"), V2 = c("2009-06-29T21:34:03+0000", 
"2010-07-10T17:11:37+0000", "2009-06-29T21:34:03+0000", "2010-07-10T17:11:37+0000", 
"2009-06-26T18:14:44+0000")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

ddf
                V1                       V2
1         Meg Bear 2009-06-29T21:34:03+0000
2 Meentiee Khurana 2010-07-10T17:11:37+0000
3         Meg Bear 2009-06-29T21:34:03+0000
4 Meentiee Khurana 2010-07-10T17:11:37+0000
5       Anjul Sahu 2009-06-26T18:14:44+0000

ll = unlist(strsplit(ddf$V2, 'T'))
ddf$V2 = ll[1:length(ll)%%2==1]

ddf
                V1         V2
1         Meg Bear 2009-06-29
2 Meentiee Khurana 2010-07-10
3         Meg Bear 2009-06-29
4 Meentiee Khurana 2010-07-10
5       Anjul Sahu 2009-06-26
```

Comment: That could just be `unlist(strsplit(ddf$V2, "T(.*)"))`. Also, aren't we using a matrix here?